# SQL Server insert statement inserting data partially. Not all given data is getting inserted

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I am inserting data into a table in my database. I recently added a new column to that table. Now I am inserting data into this table while also filling in said new column. My issue is that everything gets inserted correctly, except the data for the new column.

Can anyone help me here to get why my new column isn't getting populated?

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [data].[{tablename}] ([Id], [Name], [{new column name}])
VALUES (NEWID(), '1', '{new column value}' )
```

where:

1. `Id` is of type `[uniqueidentifier] not null unique`
2. `Name` is of type `[nvarchar] not null`
3. `[{new column name}]` is of type `[uniqueidentifier] null`

So, this insert statement get executed successfully. `Id` and `Name` columns contain some values, but that newly added third column does not contain any data.

Comment: Check for triggers on the table. If you're not doing this from Management Studio, also check for the basic "is it plugged in" condition by using Profiler to see what statements are actually going to the database. Is your table really literally named `{tablename}` or is this statement subject to pre-processing of some sort?

Comment: If you execute the insert statement with three values, the third column in the new row contains null?

Comment: yes. i have sent valid id in the insert statement. but it contains null after isert statement gets executed successfully.

Comment: Can you show sample data? Is the new column value actually a uniqueidentifier type value?

Comment: Make it a not null column and see what error you get. Just an idea for debugging.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. this table has triggers. i was not aware of this.

Comment: Strange though that an existing trigger is affecting your new column. Especially since it seems data in the other columns are there and not deleted or changed.

Comment: @WesleyNightingale it is probably an instead of trigger.

Comment: @SeanLange nice catch. Yeah, probably an insert in the trigger fired with the old table design.

Answer (score 1):

as per the above comments. table on which I was performing insert operation was having insert trigger. I just updated the trigger for newly added column and then it started working as expected.